# POST request from real android device

Tags: android

I working on android application which post its location to server. Here's one problem.

When I run this application in genymotion, it succesfully send POST requests to server. However, when I installed on samsung galaxy note, it doesn't send these post requests.

Where can be the problem?

**EDIT**: I successfully can fetch data from internet by GET request

**Code**:

```
class Posting extends AsyncTask<Location, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Location... locations){
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(RetrofitClient.API_URL2).build();

    RetrofitClient.TestRetro retrofit = restAdapter.create(RetrofitClient.TestRetro.class);
    IssdDeviceLog body=new IssdDeviceLog();
    body.setDeviceNo("hello from SAMSUNG MAIN ACTIVITY service");
    body.setLatitude(new BigDecimal(locations[0].getLatitude()));
    body.setLongtitude(new BigDecimal(locations[0].getLongitude()));
    Date date= new Date();
    body.setDate(date.toString());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(body);
    Response response=retrofit.sendLocation(json);
    Log.d("status code","   "+response.getStatus());
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    }
    }
```

With regards

Comment: If you send me a galaxy note i will find out for you ;-).

Comment: We can't really help without a piece of code or a log... -.-

Comment: @JoãoMenighin, I know that logcat is needed, but I doesn't have usb cable for this damn tablet. I do things blindly

Comment: Yeah, but without at least the code we are even more blind than you... So... :S

Comment: @JoãoMenighin, I shared code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you put your error if you getting any error  or you can use volley library i am sharing this code you can use this for your post request

```
public class send_data extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(main.this);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("please wait...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String url = "http://your_url";
        try {
            ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(
                    1);
            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key for your data","yourdata"));


            String str_responsebody = obj_service.executer(url, nvp);
            Log.i("responce", str_responsebody + "===");
            return str_responsebody;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i("error1", "" + e.toString());
            return null;
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);



        try {

            Log.i("result", result);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();


                }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error2", "" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

download volley lib and add in your project. tutorial [link]: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: There is many way to solve one problem you can try this code or it may be possible you are get the location so it may be issue of gps of your phone.